# Why is beforeDestroyed function not working?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lifecycle

I have a method which is called in the `mounted()` hook, which uses setInterval to set a time interval like below:

```
methods: {
  clock() {     
    const date = new Date()

    const hours = ((date.getHours() + 11) % 12 + 1);
    const minutes = date.getMinutes();
    const seconds = date.getSeconds();

    const hour = hours * 30;
    const minute = minutes * 6;
    const second = seconds * 6;
}},

mounted: function() {
  setInterval(this.clock, 1000);
},
```

There is another function that clears the interval in `beforeDestroyed` hook. console.log outputs "workBefore", so that I know, it's getting inside the function, but the interval is not cleared. Below is the function:

```
beforeDestroyed: function() {
  console.log("workBefore")
    clearInterval(this.clock);
  }
```

Any help is appreciated !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setInterval` returns an interval, which is used to clear the interval, which means that you need to store the `setInterval` returned value into a variable, also define the variable in the `data` object so it will be accessible everywhere in the component.

```
this.interval = setInterval(this.clock, 1000);
```

Then, use `this.interval` to clear the interval in `beforeDestroy`.

```
clearInterval(this.interval);
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked out fine. Howerve, you made a type I thinkg in the clearInterval part. This needs to be this.interval as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The below answer won't need you to have a beforeDestroy hook if all you are doing in it is to clear the interval.

```js
mounted() {
  const interval = setInterval(this.clock, 1000);
    this.$once('hook:beforeDestroy', () => {
       clearInterval(interval);
    })

},
```